# MERGE 2 csv files removing duplicates using BASH or Awk

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, merge

I have 2 csv files as given below:

Large_set.csv

```
0,116070742,34991221138,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-01 03:03:30
0,116070741,34617138590,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070743,34603492144,false,2020-02-02 15:24:31,2020-02-02 15:24:31
```

Small_set.csv

```
0,116070777,34991221138,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070422,34617138999,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
```

Requirement:

I have 2 csv files of different sizes. i want to Merge the 2 csv files by matching the 3rd column (eg.34991221138 as given here) and removing duplicates from Large_set.csv.

Expected Result:

```
0,116070777,34991221138,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070741,34617138590,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070743,34603492144,false,2020-02-02 15:24:31,2020-02-02 15:24:31
0,116070422,34617138999,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
```

I tried using `cat Large_set.csv Small_set.csv > new_set.csv` but i still cannot remove the duplicates from 1st file .
Also have checked the solutions but my requirement is to use bash script or awk (not python or any other tool like csvmerge) due to some limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about output order then using GNU sort for `-s`:

```
$ sort -t, -k3,3 -u -s small_set.csv large_set.csv
0,116070743,34603492144,false,2020-02-02 15:24:31,2020-02-02 15:24:31
0,116070741,34617138590,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070422,34617138999,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
0,116070777,34991221138,false,2020-02-02 15:24:30,2020-02-02 15:24:30
```

If you do care then you'd have to tell us what that output order should be as it's not obvious in your question.

Comment: I see the existing files are not modified. Seems i need to redirect the output to a 3rd file, correct ?

Also, my small_set.csv is the latest file. So, will this ensure ensure that matching records (3rd columns) from small_set.csv will be inluded in case duplicates are there.

Also, i need to understand the option -k3,3  and -s (stable)

Comment: Right (but "redirect" `>`, not "append" `>>`). Why would you expect the existing files to be modified and, if they were, what would you expect their contents to be?

Comment: my small_set.csv is the latest file. So, will this command ensure ensure that matching records (3rd columns) from small_set.csv will be included along with non-matching records ? Also, i need to understand the option -k3,3 and -s (stable)

Comment: Yes. You can do `man sort` of course but `-k3,3` means "use the 3 field alone for sorting" and `-s` with `-u` means "when there's 2 of the same value keep the first one". So by listing small_set.csv first it guarantees to keep it's line instead of the other files line when there's a common 3rd field value in both files. To be clear, it will keep the lines with unique values from both files as well as the common ones from small_set. It won't, for example, not print the lines from large_file that don't have a key in small_file (sorry for the double negatives - hopefully you get what I mean!).

Comment: Thanks it worked for duplicate condition on 3rd column and merging the results. In case , i need to check the duplicate condition on column 2 and column 3 both, do i need to change only -k2,3 only in the above command ?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean by that (and I think I probably do), then - yes.

Comment: How would you skip the header row of the second file?

Comment: Ask a new question.